# online web form access using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, httplib

I am trying to access websites that require login information. For practice I tried getting into Hotmail just to see if it would work. I have no idea if this code is right. With trial and error I have the code "running", but it isn't working still.. Can someone help me out?

Thanks,
Brandon

```
    Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.



import urllib.request
import webbrowser

url = 'http://hotmail.com'
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample' : 'email','idDiv_PWD_PasswordExample' : 'password'})
binary_data = data.encode('utf8')
results = urllib.request.urlopen(url, binary_data)
html = results.geturl()
print (html)
```

Answer (score 0):

## General Considerations

**Cookies** will possibly be used during the whole login process. Then the following steps can become necessary:

1. Load the login page to get the initial cookie.
2. Load the login page again, sending login data and the cookie from step 1.
3. Follow redirections after successful login.

But thanks to "batteries included", it's not that hard, I just tried the following example with the Horde Groupware:

```
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar
import urllib.parse

cookiejar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

loginpage = "https://example.com/login.php"

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))

data = {'user': 'username', 'pw': 'password'}   # + what else might be required

binData = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')

result = opener.open(loginpage)  # without credentials, to get cookie

result.read()

for c in cookiejar:    # just debugging to see if we got a cookie
  print(c)


result = opener.open(loginpage, binData)   # now send the crendentials

page = result.read().decode()              # read() will read after redirects!

f = open("out.html", "w")                  # store output in a file
f.write(page)                              # if everything worked, this should look
f.close()                                  # like the landing page
```

Please also note that most sites require **Javascript**, and Python can't handle that. I suggest that you disable Javascript in your Browser, clear all cookies from the site you try to access, and then carefully step through the process using [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and see which information (cookies, GET/POST-parameters, redirects, etc.) gets passed around for a login process. Then you can try to recreate this using python.

## Hotmail specific

Hotmail.com seems to be a suboptimal starting point to work with login forms. If you look at the source (I highly suggest [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) if you use Firefox), you can see that the "real" input field is not the `<div>` that you seem to try to use, but this one:

```
<input type="email" lang="en" name="login" id="i0116" maxlength="113"
 class="ltr_override" aria-labelledby="idLbl_PWD_Username">
```

and the password is contained in this one

```
<input type="password" name="passwd" id="i0118" autocomplete="off"
 aria-labelledby="idDiv_PWD_PasswordExample">
```

If you enter dummy (or your real) information in the input fields and try to login, you can see in Firebug's "Network" tab that some more information is sent:

```
LoginOptions    3
NewUser 1
PPFT    {very long encoded string}
PPSX    Pas
i1  0
i12 1
i13 0
i14 226
i15 2270
i17 0
i18 __Login_Strings|1,__Login_Core|1,
i2  1
i3  92877
i4  0
i7  0
idsbho  1
login   username123@example.com
passwd  password456
sso 0
type    11
```

It is possible that `login` and `password` are sufficient, but since I don't have a Hotmail account, I can't do further testing. Your general approach using urllib.request seems to be OK (except that `geturl` does exactly that, it gets an URL, so you should rename the variable html to something better).

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I tried that as well and it still isn't getting to my account. Anyone else? It definitely doesnt have to be hotmail. I have tried the same with gmail and I cant get that to work either..

Comment: I've updated my answer: Cookies may also be a reason.

Comment: Well this gives me a direction. Ill see what I can figure out. Ill try to find some tutorials on how to use things like firebug to step through this process. Thanks for all the help! Ill leave this open in case I have questions.